# Is "pedantician" a word?

Tags: nouns, suffixes, is-it-a-word, morphology, derivational-morphology

Why is someone who is pedantic called a pedant and not a "pedantician"? 
If a person working in obstetrics is an obstetrician, why is not a person working with words not a pedantician?

Comment: Aronoff (1976) called this phenomenon [blocking](http://www.glottopedia.de/index.php/Blocking).

Answer (score 6):

Because the derivations are going in opposite directions.

**Pedant** comes from Italian *pedante*, a teacher; in English it means someone who shows off his/her knowledge and constantly tries to "teach" other people, even if they don't need it.  (It does **not** mean someone working with words, although almost everyone on this site has a touch of pedantry now and then.)  If you're being **pedantic**, you are acting like a **pedant**.

An **obstetrician**, however, is a person who works in **obstetrics**.  "Obstetrics" comes from Latin *obstetrix* meaning "midwife"; the male form of *obstetrix* should be "*obstetor*", I think, but no such word exists.  Instead, we have "obstetrics" (the duties of a midwife) and "obstetrician", one who performs those duties.

Comment: Pedant comes from Italian or it comes from French  or maybe both.

Comment: @Clare - Perhaps I should have said "from Italian, by way of French"; most etymology sources show it appearing in Italian first, then being borrowed into French.  Maybe we got it from the French, maybe we got it straight from Italian; at the time it first appeared in English (around 1560), Italian literature was as commonly read in English high society as French (if not more so.

Answer (score 3):

The reason there is no such word as "pedantrician" lies in the difference between the word pedantic and obstretics.

"Obstetrics" is a noun, and "pedantic" is an adjective.

"Pedantic" is derived from ["pedant"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pedantic), but "obstetician" is derived from "obstetics"

The reason there is no "pedantrician", is because "pedant" is not a study, unlike "obstetrics." No one is an expert or a doctor or practices in "pedant"